# Linear operations on packed Shamir secret share

Tags: secret-sharing

Suppose I have a k-dimensional secret $\langle x_1,\cdots,x_k \rangle$ which I share using a packed Shamir's secret share $(t,k,n)$ where $t$ is the threshold and $n$ is the number of shares as follows:
Construct a polynomial $f$ of degree $t+k-1$ such that $f(-1)=x_1, \cdots, f(-k)=x_k, f(-k-1)=r_1, \cdots, f(-k-t)=r_t$ where $r_1,\cdots,r_k$ are randomly sampled from the field. Now the n shares are generated as $(1,f(1)),\cdots,(n,f(n))$.
Let's say every party $i $ has share $(i,f(i))$ and two $k$-dimensional public vectors $\langle a_1,\cdots,a_k\rangle, \langle b_1,\cdots, b_k \rangle$. Is it possible to compete linear operations on the packed shares, i.e., generate the share for $\langle x_1\cdot a_1+b_1,\cdots,x_k\cdot a_k+b_k\rangle$?

I want to be able to do it non-trivially, i.e., not by reconstructing the secret and then computing on the clear. Basically, is it possible to perform SIMD linear operations on the packed shares *locally*? Note that when $a_1=a_2\cdots=a_k:=a, b_1=b_2\cdots=b_k:=b$ it is possible to obtain the shares as $(i,a\cdot f(i)+b)$. But I am interested in the more general case where $a_i/b_i$s are different.

Comment: To get meaningful answers you should probably specify the restrictions on how to achieve this. I.e., what security properties are you looking for? Because it is trivially "possible" to compute this, by reconstructing the secret and computing the linear operations in the clear. But that is probably not the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Also note that this "packed Shamir" scheme doesn't have the informational security properties of standard Shamir - if the attacker learns/guesses (say) $x_1$, the number of valid shares he need to recover the rest is reduced by one.  The same holds for any linear combination of the $x_i$ values.  Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: I see, I was trying to do this "packing" to reduce communication bandwidth. Is there a good reference for the security properties of packed or ramp Shamir?